# Select All Option in Angular 6+

Tags: angular, mat-form-field

I am having trouble Creating a Select All option in a Mat-select field in Angular and passing the id to another ngModel.

#### Template.html

`<form [formGroup]="composeGroup"> <mat-form-field> <mat-select id="groupIds" formControlName="groupIds" multiple [(ngModel)]="composeCreateMessage.groupIds"> <mat-option (click)="selectAllGroups()">Select All</mat-option> <mat-option *ngFor="let group of groups; let i=index" [value]="groups[i].id">{{ group[i].name}}</mat-option> </mat-select> </mat-form-field> </form>`

So I am looping through the groups that i am grabbing from an api on ngOnInit and pushing the id of the selected group

The group model looks as such
{ id: 1, name = "Admin", level: 2, updatedDate : ..., createDate: ...}

#### Componnent.ts

```
public composeGroup: FormGroup;
public groups: Group[];

constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    public userService: UserService
){
    this.composeGroup = fb.group({
        groupIds: [],
        sentFrom: null
    });
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.userService.getGroups().subscribe((res) =>{
        this.groups = res;
    })
}

selectAllGroups(){
    // Need to push all groups into composeGroup.groupIds if Select All option is choosen
    
    // Also need to update the UI checkbox to select all
}
```

#### component.ts

Comment: Before doing anything, choose to either use reactive form or template driven form, they are not to be used together.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
selectAllGroups(){
    this.composeGroup.patchValue({ groupIds: this.groups });
}
```

?
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchValue

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.  When i click the option to selectAllGroups() the button is not checking.  I think It has something to do with the structure of this.groups.  In the original post i said { id: 1, name = "Admin", level: 2, updatedDate : ..., createDate: ...}.  My mistake.  It is [{ id: 1, name = "Admin", level: 2, updatedDate : ..., createDate: ...}, { id: 2, name = "User", level: 2, updatedDate : ..., createDate: ...},..].  Not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: Ended up getting it to work.    selectAllGroups(){
  let groupsValues = [];
  for(let group of this.groups){
   groupsValues.push(group.id)
  }
  this.composeGroup.patchValue({groupIds: groupValues});
 }. THANK YOU :-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment on the initial post - remove ngModel (or do not use formControl). As for the question, the answer below is almost correct - as the values in your mat-options are ids, the value set with patchValue has to be a list of ids (not the full objects). This should work, still on one line:

```
selectAllGroups(){
    this.composeGroup.patchValue({ groupIds: this.groups?.map(x => x.id) });
}
```